# Who invented/introduced the notion of convergence in probability and convergence in measure?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, math-history

There are many notions of convergence in the field of probability but one of them is called "convergence in probability".

Who invented/introduced this notion of convergence?

Was the same notion of convergence already there in measure theory?

Comment: There are multiple notions of convergence in probability.  Do you want to be more specific?

Comment: There are many notions of convergence in the field of probability but one of them is called "convergence in probability".

Comment: OK.  The wording of the question should make it clear you want that.

Comment: Convergence in probability is a fancy way of saying "convergence in measure," as the only real difference is that probability measures are normalized to 1.

Comment: Then, who invented/introduced "convergence in measure"?

Comment: @Aristodog Bogachev, in his book Measure Theory (Vol. 1), claims that Borel and Lebesgue were aware of convergence in measure, and that the concept also went by "asymptotic convergence" (p.426). In particular it is claimed that Lebesgue used "a.e. convergence implies convergence in measure" in his 1906 book "Leçons sur les séries trigonométriques" (which I didn't check but the book is available at https://archive.org/details/leonssurlessrie01lebegoog).

Comment: In any event, if this question is asked on the history of science and math SE it's more likely to get the attention it deserves.